# Vaadin integration of existing database

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, vaadin

Hi I'm trying to implement a class dbHelper to create a connection to an existing database on the phpmyadmin site.
I want to read and edit entries in the database. So my question is, how you would recommend to implement this in vaadin.

Comment: Depends what functionaility you need. But the SQLContainer would be a good start, or perhaps the JPAContainer as well... https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-overview.html and https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/sqlcontainer/sqlcontainer-architecture.html

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an application for accessing a MariaDB or MySQL database. Perhaps you mean one of those instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to create an application that supports create, read, update and delete (an acronym **CRUD**), which are the four basic functions of persistent storage.

Tutorials for creating CRUD applications with Vaadin has been done quite a few times. The article [Creating CRUD UI with Vaadin](https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/) as well as [Spring Data JPA CRUD with Vaadin](https://github.com/mstahv/spring-data-vaadin-crud) git repository provide a good step-by-step instructional. As @Andre recommended, using JPAContainers and [Bean Item Containers](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/BeanItemContainer.html) are going to cut down the amount of code you need to write, so it would be worth your time planning your data models accordingly. If you have any specific questions on accessing data with JPA, or anything else please let me know!